# Performance issues with animations (background highlighting)

Tags: discussion, design, performance

I have performance issues in following cases:

- When I follow the link to a particular answer, it focuses on the answer within the page, but also shows an animated fading orange background. It happens however very slowly, sometimes focusing is jumping around the page before it goes to the correct position. The color animation is never smooth for me.
- Similar (but less visually noticeable) issues I see when I click on "show all comments".

I personally would not suffer if there were no animations, if it could improve the navigation performance, I'd say probably turn it off completely or think of some alternative to it.

Especially on a weak PC the slowdown is very noticeable, sometimes I wait to 5 seconds before I see all comments. But I am not sure if it is caused by the animation in the first place.

I use Firefox.

Comment: Do the post have complex/heavy images or other resource?

Comment: I notice this too - especially on my tablet when using the desktop site.

Comment: @Braiam Hmm, I can't tell for sure, I need to test it for different cases. But I noticed that the delay before showing the comments has a very random character, even if theres only few comments.

Comment: @Braiam I think you're right,  threads/post with less images and lighter structure has way less delays and animation is smoother.